# In google app scripts how can i get an onEdit popup when a column or row is added?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here is my code

```
    function onEdit(e) {
  var sheetName = "TRK";
  var range = e.range;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  
  // Check if the edited sheet is the TRK sheet and if it's in the first 11 rows
  if (sheet.getName() === sheetName && range.getRow() <= 11) {
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    
    // Show a warning message
    ui.alert('Adding Rows Guidelines', 'If you need to add or delete rows, please do so between rows 11 and 49.', ui.ButtonSet.OK);

    // Cancel the attempt to add or delete rows
    e.range.setValue(""); // Remove the added value to cancel the edit
  }
}
```

For some reason i cant get this to work, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm curious as to why you don't wish to use Protection on the first eleven lines. [Protection](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection)

Comment: in have title rows and some other things to the right in those rows. adding and removing would move those things around and i have dependencies on the locations of certain content.

Comment: The onEdit trigger does fire on inserting rows or columns but not on deleting them.

Comment: The problem is that there is no difference to the event object between adding a row and clearing one  cell so you don't really know if you need to eliminate the row unless you can put a target somewhere on the sheet to keep track of the  number of lines between it and the top.

Comment: Hi. The question title isn't meant to be a substitute for a more complete description of the scenario _and_ problem in the body of the question. Having said that, if you want to track when `a column or row is added`, then perhaps `onChange` (an installable trigger) would be a better choice.